# timed notification without using service

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I know there any many questions like my question , I've read many of them, and now I'm really confused that is it really possible to show a notification when the activity has been destroyed and our app is not in memory.
here is the scenario:
My app is in the memory and the user select a time in the future then the app must show a notification and then he/she will close the app.I really want to do it without writing a service. Is it possible? how?

I have tested using alarm manager but when user completely close the app , the timed notifications doesn't work.And the timed notifications can be more than one.

Comment: Yes you can do it with AlarmManager..

Comment: How? that's the problem and without using service

Comment: Here you will write one receiver which will called at your specified time..there you can send notification..

Comment: even when the activity is completely closed?!

Comment: yes..no activity is running or present at that time.

Comment: I tested that but I'll try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `BroadCastReceiver` declared in your manifest and a launch a `PendingIntent` for the time you want the notification to launch. Then it's a matter of creating said notification on the `onReceive` method of the `BroadCastReceiver`.